# add rows to table with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to use JavaScript or ASP C# to add rows to a table in form when the user clicks the add row button. I have working code in JavaScript. I want to add the rows with text input boxes inside of the `<td></td>` tags. The row count is in my code becasue I am attempting to use it to add IDs to each element for use later.

```js
element.innerHTML(<input id="tagcell"+(rowcount+1)+"" type="text"/>);
```

```js
  function addrow() {
     var rowcount = 
     document.getElementById('tbl').getElementsByTagName('tbody').length;
     window.alert(rowcount);
     var tableRef = document.getElementById('tbl').getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];
     var newRow   = tableRef.insertRow(tableRef.rows.length);

     // Insert a cell in the row at index 0
     var tagcell  = newRow.insertCell(0);
     var desccell = newRow.insertCell(1);
     var loccell  = newRow.insertCell(2);
     var Namecell = newRow.insertCell(3);
     var Sigcell  = newRow.insertCell(4);

     tagcell.innerHTML = "";
     desccell.innerHTML="";
     loccell.innerHTML = "";
     Namecell.innerHTML="";
     Sigcell.innerHTML = "";

  }
```

```html
   <table id=tbl>
    <tr>
        <td id=tag_no>Col1</td>
        <td id=desc> Col2</td>
        <td id=loc> col3</td>
        <td id=nme> col4</td>
        <td id=sig> col5</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<input type="button" value="clickme" onclick="addrow()" />
```

Comment: Your code does not work. Please throw it in a CodePen so we can see it working. Then we'll answer your question. :)

Comment: @GabeRogan It works... you just need to put some content into the inserted cells to have them show up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how you could do that. (Obviously you can style the text boxes however you want.)  Your code added the rows; I just added a `textarea` in each cell.

```js
function addrow() {
     var tableRef = document.getElementById('tbl').getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];
     var rowcount = tableRef.rows.length;
     window.alert(rowcount);
     var newRow   = tableRef.insertRow(tableRef.rows.length);
     var textBox = "<textarea></textarea>";
     
     // Insert a cell in the row at index 0
     var tagcell  = newRow.insertCell(0);
     var desccell = newRow.insertCell(1);
     var loccell  = newRow.insertCell(2);
     var Namecell = newRow.insertCell(3);
     var Sigcell  = newRow.insertCell(4);

     tagcell.innerHTML = textBox;
     desccell.innerHTML= textBox;
     loccell.innerHTML = textBox;
     Namecell.innerHTML= textBox;
     Sigcell.innerHTML = textBox;

  }
```

```html
<table id=tbl>
    <tr>
        <td id=tag_no>Col1</td>
        <td id=desc> Col2</td>
        <td id=loc> col3</td>
        <td id=nme> col4</td>
        <td id=sig> col5</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<input type="button" value="clickme" onclick="addrow()" />
```

**EDIT:** Your row count shows the correct number now.  (It was only showing `1` each time before.)

Answer (score 0):

```
function addrow() {
    var myTable = document.querySelector('#tbl');
    var row = myTable .insertRow(0);
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    cell1.innerHTML = 'My first cell';

    // and so on for other cells
}
```

p.s. please add "" to all your HTML attributes values. For example

```
<table id="tbl">
```